# How can I use py2exe with arcpy?

Tags: python, py2exe, arcpy

I'm trying to convert a python script to a stand-alone executable using py2exe. The script is built mostly using arcpy, with a Tkinter GUI.

The setup.py script is as follows:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

script = r"pathtoscript.py"

options = {'py2exe':{
    "includes": ['arcpy', 'arcgisscripting'],
    "packages": ['arcpy', 'arcgisscripting'],
    "dll_excludes": ["mswsock.dll", "powrprof.dll"]
    }}

setup(windows=[script], options=options)
```

When run, setup.py creates the .exe as expected, but when I try to run the executable, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "autolim.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "arcpy\__init__.pyc", line 21, in <module>
  File "arcpy\geoprocessing\__init__.pyc", line 14, in <module>
  File "arcpy\geoprocessing\_base.pyc", line 14, in <module>
  File "arcgisscripting.pyc", line 12, in <module>
  File "arcgisscripting.pyc", line 10, in __load
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

I use python 2.7 and arcgis 10.1 - feel free to ask if I've forgotten any useful information.

Can anyone tell me what I need to do to get the executable working properly?

Many thanks!

Comment: Are you assuming that end-users will have ArcGIS installed? Isn't that required in order to use Arcpy?

Comment: 2nd what @jozzas said, py2exe wont bundle arcpy into a sell contained exe. The arcpy package has a lot of dependencies outside arcgisscripting.pyd

Comment: @jozzas, that's correct. The end user will definitely have ArcGIS installed. From what I can see, py2exe has bundled most dependencies but has missed arcgisscripting.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem...

Since your users will have python/arcpy installed on their machines have your arcpy scripts in a data_files directory.

```
setup(windows=[script], data_files=[('scripts', glob(r'/path/to/scripts/*.py')], options=options)
```

Then call them using [subprocess.Popen](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen)

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen(r'python "%s\scripts\autolim.py"' % self.basedir)
```

Popen is non-blocking so it won't freeze your GUI while the arcpy script runs.

If you want to print any print statements in your arcpy script change to

```
p = subprocess.Popen(r'python "%s\scripts\autolim.py"' % self.basedir, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

while True:
    line = p.stdout.readline()
    if not line:
        break
    sys.stdout.write(line)
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you see this step: https://community.esri.com/t5/python-questions/using-py2exe-with-arcpy-it-can-be-done-easily/td-p/360520

You must add exclude in setup options and copy the site-packages path.
I have tried it and it works.